# Fantasy middle-ages animated series on YouTube featuring ninjas and a "this is my horse" cameo appearance ~2010

Tags: story-identification, animated-series

I can't remember the title of a fantasy middle-ages animated series on YouTube. It was humorous, a bit brutal and featured ninjas as the bad guys. I think there was a cameo appearance of "[this is my horse, my horse is amazing](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/amazing-horse)". In the beginning there was a scene, where soldiers crashed a door and the main character got drafted. There was also some wizard, who supported the main character, but was quite careless.

I also remember, there was a franchise Flash game, were you could fight ninjas on rooftops, which was a bit like a platformer. I thought it was by AdultSwim, but could not find it.

Thanks for your help =)

Comment: An Adult Swim game fighting ninja on rooftops sounds a bit like [House of Dead Ninjas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_House_of_Dead_Ninjas) but it doesn't look that's based on a series.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I also found that one, but that's not it. Probably the game was not by AdultSwim in the end...